# unsure how to rearrange $f(x)$ into suitable $p(x)/q(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

Consider the function $f(x)= (x^3 + 2x - 3) / (x^2 + 3x + 4)$

by dividing the numerator and denominator by the highest power of $x$ present, convert $f(x)$ into the form $P(x)/Q(x)$ where both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ have finite limits as '$x$ tends to infinity', not both $0$.

I know I am supposed to divide the numerator and denominator separately, however when it says 'by the highest power of $x$ present', does this mean

present in itself (ie numerator OR denominator) or the fuction $f(x)$ as a whole, (ie in this question $x^3$) I have assumed its the highest power of $x$ present in the whole function $f(x)$, and I have ended up with

$$
(1 + 2x^{-2} - 3x^{-3}) / (x^{-1} + 3x^{-2} + 4x^{-3})
$$

and I do not know where to go from here.

not entirely sure how to rearrange negative powers. ie, if theres a negative power

can I just swap that term from the top to the bottom or vice versa?

Comment: please use LaTex

Comment: The trick of dividing through by the highest power of $x$ doesn't really help with this limit.  You end up with the denominator going to zero and the numerator going to 1, thus the ratio goes to infinity.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Why should it not go to infinity either way? We have $x^3$ in the numerator and $x^2$ in the denominator as dominant terms, and $x^3/x^2=x$ tends to infinity anyway.

Comment: Exactly, it obviously goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide not by $x^3$ but $x^2$ to get

$$\frac{x^3+2x-3}{x^2+3x+4}\underset{x>0}{=}\frac{x+2/x-3/x^2}{1+3/x+4/x^2}\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\sim} \frac{x}{1}=x.$$

$x$ is said to be an *asymptotic* of $f(x)$ and we write $f(x)\sim x$ (for $x$ large).

Comment: i think this is what i need to be doing, but i think it needs to be rearranged differently. the numerator and denominator a separate polynomials should tend to a finite value. right now the numerator will tend to infinity or (x).

Comment: According to a later part of the question the limit of the function f(x) DNE.
therefore, im not sure that what youve done showing that it tends to x or infinity is correct?

Comment: Yes the numerator tends to infinity. Well as $x$ goes to infinity, $f(x)$ begins to look like $x$ (in the sense that the percentage difference between them goes to zero), and if $x$ goes to infinity so does $x$... 30% at $x=10$, 3% at $x=100$ and 0.3% at $x=1000$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B%28x%5E3%2B2x-3%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B3x%2B4%29%2Cx%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C200%7D%5D

Comment: ohk but in order to answer the question properly, each polynomial P(x) and Q(x) should separately tend to a finite value. not worried about what f(x) tends to as a whole right now :\

Comment: @DanielCongedi your question does not say that $P$ and $Q$ should be polynomials. In fact, they can't be, because non-constant polynomials never have limits at infinity.

Comment: ohk sorry they dont have to necessarily be polynomials, but it asks that the numerator and denominator when looked at as separate terms (arguments), P(x)/Q(x) then individually they must tend to a finite value.

Comment: @DanielCongedi As $x\rightarrow \infty$, considered "separately", ALL non-constant polynomials tend not to a finite value, but $\pm\infty$.

Comment: ...do you not get it... the 'limit' is infinite... the question can't be done in the terms you are asking. The two answers here tell you what to do in this case... $f(x)\sim x$ so as $x$ gets big $f(x)$ gets big too.

Comment: ...or else, do what you have with $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1+2/x^2-3/x^3}{1/x+3/x^2+4/x^3}=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$... now $P(x)\rightarrow 1$ and $Q(x)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: thankyou for all your help, turns out i was right the whole time, the program i was entering answers in is a piece of utter buLLcr*p sh!t.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the exercise you were doing to be quite honest with you.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer fits the literal instructions of the question. However, I'm not sure why it's a useful thing to do. Your question as stated does not ask you to evaluate the limit, so you're done.

If I were to write the question, I would say to do the following:

$$\frac{x^3 + 2x -1}{x^2 + 3x + 4} = \frac{x^3(1 + 2x^{-2} -x^{-3})}{x^2(1 + 3x^{-1} + 4x^{-2})} \sim x$$